# Не запускается python скрипт Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, systemd

Не запускается `python` скрипт с ошибкой `Failed with result 'start-limit-hit`.

Файл `bot.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=test-bot
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/root/main.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Запускаю как обычно

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable bot.service
systemctl start bot.service
systemctl status bot.service -> получаю ошибку выше
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ошибку приложите, мы же не телепаты. Скрипт вручную вне сервиса запускается?

Comment: @ГеннадийП Failed with result 'start-limit-hit' вот и вся ошибка

Comment: Уберите `Restart=always`, перезапустите сервис и посмотрите через `systemctl status bot.service` что он там пишет.

Comment: @ГеннадийП заработало, спасибо. Подскажите, он при каждом перезапуске системы теперь стартовать будет?  И почему эта строчка мешала?

Comment: Не знаю, Обычно ошибка в логах пишется в самом начале, поэтому и рекомендуют убрать рестарт и смотреть ошибку. А с рестартом она теряется, что мешает локализовать проблему. Понаблюдайте за сервисом, если упадет - увидите ошибку в логах. И также рекомендуется не сразу перезапускать, а делать задержку рестарта.